# Out of close votes: 1-1=?

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

After running out of close votes (*Please, sir, I want some more*), the count at the bottom of the popup shows no number. Not zero, just no number.

[image: votes remaining]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (happening in a few hours).